# Spring AMQP - nothing showing up in dead letter queue

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have what seems to be a correctly configured RabbitMQ queue (shows the dlx argument) and in my Java listener code, I throw a `FatalListenerExecutionException`. For some reason, nothing is showing up in the designated dead letter queue after the exception is thrown.

Am I throwing the wrong kind of exception?

Thanks.

Queue instantiation in Spring configuration:

```
Map arguments = new HashMap();
arguments.put("x-dead-letter-exchange", "dlx.queue");
new Queue("some.queue", true, false, false, arguments);
```

Listener Container in Spring configuration:

```
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer 
someContainer(){
        final SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        container.setQueues(createTheQueue());
        container.setMessageListener(theListener());
        container.setConcurrentConsumers(numberOfConcurrentConsumers);
        container.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(maxDefaultConsumers);
        container.setDefaultRequeueRejected(false);
        return container;
    }
```

Bindings for "some.queue" shown in RabbitMQ console:

```
Parameters : x-dead-letter-exchange:    dlx.queue
```

Answer (score 1):

You must throw `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException` or there is just enough to setup `defaultRequeuRejected="false"` for the listener container.

See the test-case from Spring AMQP: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/master/spring-rabbit/src/test/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/core/FixedReplyQueueDeadLetterTests.java

Comment: Thanks. I actually have defaultRequeuRejected="false".

Comment: You need to show your  configuration including the DLX/DLQ binding.

Comment: Thanks. I added detail to the original question.

Comment: Added a link to the test-case on the matter and based on the Java Config. You should be sure that you have an Excahnge for Dead letter and some binded queue to receive those dead messages.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I just needed to specify the routing key (since it's a direct exchange and not a fanout). I learned that from this question:

[RabbitMQ dead letter exchange never getting messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21742232/rabbitmq-dead-letter-exchange-never-getting-messages)