# Rabbit-Mq not routing to dead letter queue after being rejected

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I'm currently playing around with Rabbit-Mq, and am trying to implement a "dead-letter" queue, a queue for failed messages. I've been reading the rabbit documentation: https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html.

and have come up with this example:

```
internal class Program
{
    private const string WorkerExchange = "work.exchange";
    private const string RetryExchange = "retry.exchange";
    public const string WorkerQueue = "work.queue";
    private const string RetryQueue = "retry.queue";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var factory = new ConnectionFactory { HostName = "localhost" };

        using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        {
            using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
            {
                channel.ExchangeDeclare(WorkerExchange, "direct");
                channel.QueueDeclare
                (
                    WorkerQueue, true, false, false,
                    new Dictionary<string, object>
                    {
                        {"x-dead-letter-exchange", RetryExchange},

                        // I have tried with and without this next key
                        {"x-dead-letter-routing-key", RetryQueue}
                    }
                );
                channel.QueueBind(WorkerQueue, WorkerExchange, string.Empty, null);

                channel.ExchangeDeclare(RetryExchange, "direct");
                channel.QueueDeclare
                (
                    RetryQueue, true, false, false,
                    new Dictionary<string, object> {
                        { "x-dead-letter-exchange", WorkerExchange },
                        { "x-message-ttl", 30000 },
                    }
                );
                channel.QueueBind(RetryQueue, RetryExchange, string.Empty, null);

                var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
                consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
                {
                    var body = ea.Body;
                    var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                    Console.WriteLine(" [x] Received {0}", message);

                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    Console.WriteLine("Rejected message");

                    // also tried  channel.BasicNack(ea.DeliveryTag, false, false);
                    channel.BasicReject(ea.DeliveryTag, false);
                };

                channel.BasicConsume(WorkerQueue, false, consumer);

                Console.WriteLine(" Press [enter] to exit.");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Image of queue when publishing to worker queue:
[image: rabbit-mq worker queue stats]

Image of the retry queue:
[image: rabbit-mq retry stats]

I feel as though I'm missing some small details but can't seem to find what they are.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should define your dead-letter-exchange as `fanout`.

There we go:  `channel.ExchangeDeclare(RetryExchange, "fanout");`

> If your dead letter exchange is setup as DIRECT you must specify a
>   dead letter routing key. If you just want all your NACKed message to
>   go into a dead letter bucket for later investigation (as I do) then
>   your dead letter exchange should be setup as a FANOUT.
>
> [Look at this for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21864158/2669438)

Comment: Thank you! Didn't see that answer, was searching for quite a while

Comment: I also figured out that the "x-dead-letter-routing-key" wasn't working because I didn't specify a routing key on the binding and was assuming it would route via queue name, which was a poor, unfounded assumption

Answer (score 7):

Turns out that if a dead letter exchange is a `direct` exchange then the queue parameters require a `x-dead-letter-routing-key`. Above (in the question) I am using this key in the dictionary to try and route my messages but what I am not doing is adding a route to my binding, here is an updated version of the code that works:

```
internal class Program
{
    private const string WorkerExchange = "work.exchange";
    private const string RetryExchange = "retry.exchange";
    public const string WorkerQueue = "work.queue";
    private const string RetryQueue = "retry.queue";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var factory = new ConnectionFactory { HostName = "localhost" };

        using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        {
            using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
            {
                channel.ExchangeDeclare(WorkerExchange, "direct");
                channel.QueueDeclare
                (
                    WorkerQueue, true, false, false,
                    new Dictionary<string, object>
                    {
                        {"x-dead-letter-exchange", RetryExchange},
                        {"x-dead-letter-routing-key", RetryQueue}
                    }
                );
                channel.QueueBind(WorkerQueue, WorkerExchange, WorkerQueue, null);

                channel.ExchangeDeclare(RetryExchange, "direct");
                channel.QueueDeclare
                (
                    RetryQueue, true, false, false,
                    new Dictionary<string, object>
                    {
                        {"x-dead-letter-exchange", WorkerExchange},
                        {"x-dead-letter-routing-key", WorkerQueue},
                        {"x-message-ttl", 30000},
                    }
                );
                channel.QueueBind(RetryQueue, RetryExchange, RetryQueue, null);

                var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
                consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
                {
                    var body = ea.Body;
                    var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                    Console.WriteLine(" [x] Received {0}", message);

                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    Console.WriteLine("Rejected message");
                    channel.BasicNack(ea.DeliveryTag, false, false);
                };

                channel.BasicConsume(WorkerQueue, false, consumer);

                Console.WriteLine(" Press [enter] to exit.");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

The difference being that the call to `channel.QueueBind(WorkerQueue, WorkerExchange, WorkerQueue, null);` now supplies the routing key to be the same as the queuename, so when the message "dead-letters" it gets routed to the exchange via this key

Answer (score 0):

The main thing to make it work is to bind WorkerExchange and WorkerQueue **with the exact routing key.** 
It should be configured via RabbitMq UI Manager for work.exchange.

**Then add messages to the WorkerQueue via WorkerExchange using this routing key.**
Then these "dead queue" messages will be stored in retry.queue

```
channel.QueueDeclare
            (
                WorkerQueue, true, false, false,
                new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    {"x-dead-letter-exchange", RetryExchange}
                }
            );
```

This is what you need for queue declaration in your C# code.

Extra argument `{"x-dead-letter-routing-key", RetryQueue}` is not needed.

The following lines of code are not needed too:

```
channel.ExchangeDeclare(WorkerExchange, "direct");

channel.QueueBind(WorkerQueue, WorkerExchange, WorkerQueue, null);

channel.ExchangeDeclare(RetryExchange, "direct");
channel.QueueDeclare
            (
                RetryQueue, true, false, false,
                new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    {"x-dead-letter-exchange", WorkerExchange},
                    {"x-dead-letter-routing-key", WorkerQueue},
                    {"x-message-ttl", 30000},
                }
            );
channel.QueueBind(RetryQueue, RetryExchange, RetryQueue, null);
```

So you can remove the above lines.